# Kleene closure of a disjunctive normal form for regular expressions

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions, disjunctive-normal-form

$\newcommand{\Kstar}[1]{#1^\ast}$
I would like to write the regular expression
$$
a^\ast b^\ast + ( a + b )^\ast b a ( a + b )^\ast
$$
as a Kleene closure of a *union of catenations* or in other words, a Kleene closure of something akin to a disjunctive normal form of regular expressions. I didn't immediately see what operations I would have to use to get there, so I started by applying the regular language function $K$ to the regex to see where it would take me:
\begin{align*}
  &K(a^\ast b^\ast + ( a + b )^\ast b a ( a + b )^\ast ) \\
  &= K(a^\ast b^\ast) \cup K( ( a + b )^\ast b a ( a + b )^\ast ) \\
  &= K(a^\ast)K(b^\ast) \cup K(( a + b )^\ast) K( b a ) K( ( a + b )^\ast ) \\
  &= K(a)^\ast K(b)^\ast \cup K( a + b )^\ast K( b a ) K(  a + b  )^\ast \\
  &= K(a)^\ast K(b)^\ast \cup ( K(a) \cup K(b) )^\ast K( b a ) ( K(a) \cup K(b) )^\ast \\
&= K(a)^\ast K(b)^\ast \cup ( K(a)^\ast \cup K(b)^\ast )^\ast K( b a ) ( K(a)^\ast \cup K(b)^\ast )^\ast \,.
\end{align*}

However, this does not look very promising, at least not at the moment. If I understood the question correctly, I would need to be able to somehow get a single Kleene closure out of the entire expression, but that does not seem possible.

Does anyone have any pointers towards possible calculation rules that might simplify this further and make the final form easier to spot?

#### Edit

It looks like there exists a rule that says the following: for any regular expressions $s$ and $r$, $(s + r)^\ast \equiv (s^\ast r^\ast)^\ast$, as in the two regular expressions are semantically equivalent. This already results in
\begin{align}
a^\ast b^\ast + ( a + b )^\ast b a ( a + b )^\ast\equiv a^\ast b^\ast + ( a^\ast b^\ast )^\ast b a ( a^\ast b^\ast )^\ast
\end{align}
and our regular expression is in disjunctive normal form. However, this is still ways away from only a single Kleene closure being present in the expression.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. As a regular language, one has $a^\ast b^\ast + ( a + b )^\ast b a ( a + b )^\ast = ( a + b )^\ast$. What is $K$ in your question?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin $K(r)$ is the regular language produced by the regular expression $r$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin So the answer to this question would be $(a + b)^\ast = (a^\ast b^\ast)^\ast$, if what you claim is true. I just don't see the connection, or equivalence of the expressions yet. How did you arrive at the answer?

Comment: $a^*b^*$ is the complement of the language $(a+b)^*ba(a+b)^*$. More details if needed in a few hours --- I have to go.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. The regex $a^\ast b^\ast$ produces strings which start with a sequence of the letter $a$ and end with a sequence of $b$s and only those. The regex $$(a+b)^\ast ba (a+b)^\ast$$ produces every other type of string in the given alphabet: non-empty strings that have alternating $a$s and $b$s, strings that start with a sequence of $b$s and end with a sequence of $a$s, and so forth. Therefore the regexes complement each other. The union of a regex and its complement produces every possible string in the alphabet, meaning we get the language  $\{a, b\}^\ast = K( (a + b)^\ast )$.